# Why is the hash function O(1)

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, hash

Why does finding the hash of a given string only run in constant time?

I am trying to write an optimized program to compare two strings by using string hashing.

From what I know, the hash of a string is usually defined by a polynomial rolling hash function. Online sources say calculating this hash and doing the comparison is O(1). For example, https://cp-algorithms.com/string/string-hashing.html says that

> The idea behind the string hashing is the following: we map each string into an integer and compare those instead of the strings. Doing this allows us to reduce the execution time of the string comparison to O(1).

However, the actual implementation (according to https://cp-algorithms.com/string/string-hashing.html) of this hash function includes looping through the entire string:

```
long long compute_hash(string const& s) {
const int p = 31;
const int m = 1e9 + 9;
long long hash_value = 0;
long long p_pow = 1;
for (char c : s) {
    hash_value = (hash_value + (c - 'a' + 1) * p_pow) % m;
    p_pow = (p_pow * p) % m;
}
return hash_value;
}
```

Wouldn't this guarantee linear time complexity to compare two strings, instead of O(1)?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Re: "Why does finding the hash of a given string only run in constant time?": It doesn't; but if you edit the question to explain why you think it does, someone can probably clarify for you whatever it is that you've misunderstood.

Comment: Big O can be a little relative. This hashing algorithm is O(n) where n is the size of the string, but that has nothing to do with the size of the list of strings that the hash table is concerned about. If you care only about the amount of look-ups you need to find an item in the hash table, that's mostly O(1). Also note that the hash values can be computed once, cached and then repeatedly used at O(1) for an amortized O(1).

Comment: I don't think that you can reasonably cache the hash values, @user4581301. You'd need a mapping from a value to its cached hash, but that would in turn require an implementation based on either a tree or a hash map again.

Comment: In theory you'll have some mean length of string which will be your actual cost.  It just means that your hash has a high "constant" factor.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt In this case, probably not. There could be a wrapper around `std::string` that records the hash value along with the `string`, but I doubt that's the case here.

Comment: Unless it is an exercise, the C++ standard library offers hashing support for many types, including std:: string. (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/hash).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Big-O notation is a way of describing how the execution time of an algorithm will grow with the size of the data-set it is working on.  In order for that definition to be applied, we have to specify what the data-set is that will be growing.

In most cases that's obvious, but sometimes it's a bit ambiguous, and this is one of those cases.  Does "data set" in this case refer to an individual string?  If so, then the algorithm is O(N), since the sequence of operations it has to perform grows linearly with the size of the string.  But if by "data set" you mean the number of items in the associated hash table, then the algorithm can be considered O(1), since it will operate just as quickly (for any given string) when dealing with a million-entry Hashtable as it would for a two-entry Hashtable.

Regarding using hashing to compare two strings:  once you have computed the hash values for the two strings, and stored those hash values somewhere, you can compare the two hash values in O(1) time (since comparing two integers is a fixed-cost operation, regardless of the sizes of the strings they were calculated from).  It's important to note, however, that this comparison can only tell you if the two strings are different -- if the two hash values are equal, you still can't be 100% certain that the two strings are equal, since (due to the pigeonhole principle) two different strings can hash to the same value.  So in that case you'd still need to compare the strings the regular O(N)/char-by-char way.

Answer (score 2):

> The idea behind the string hashing is the following: we map each string into an integer and compare those instead of the strings. Doing this allows us to reduce the execution time of the string comparison to O(1).

This sentence is quite misleading.

As you figured out computing the hash of a string takes O(n) time. But once you have computed the hash you can compare strings by comparing their hashes. The paragraph only refers to the comparison of hashes, which is O(1).

But even then it's false to say the string comparison becomes O(1). The string comparison is only O(1) when the hash doesn't match. A matching hash does not guarantee the strings are the same and you have to double check by comparing the actual strings, which is O(n).

So what the hashing gives you is the ability to quickly detect that 2 strings are not equal in most cases. If you only want to compare 2 strings then it is utterly pointless. String hashing is only worth it if you compare many times. You need to compute the hash, store it and use it more than once to get any benefit.

PS: Some application pretend that hash collisions don't happen and that 2 strings are equal if their hashes match. When using a strong cryptographic hash this is a near certainty. But a collision is not impossible, they are playing russian roulette.